# JIRA, get a parent issue via SOAP api

Tags: api, soap, jira

I need to obtain a parent issue of given issue via SOAP API, or even using database. It seems to be very basic objective, however I didn't find any useful information in internet. Besides, I didn't find any fields in jira's db tables (jiraissue) to set the parent issue of an issue.

Additional info: Jira 5.1, c# .Net

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no way to do this using the SOAP directly.

One possible solution would be using [the Jira Scripting Suite](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/16346). You can create a post-function that will run after the `Open` status that will copy the parent to a custom field using [getParentObject](http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/4.0/com/atlassian/jira/issue/Issue.html#getParentObject%28%29). Then you could use the SOAP function [getCustomFields](http://docs.atlassian.com/rpc-jira-plugin/latest/com/atlassian/jira/rpc/soap/JiraSoapService.html#getCustomFields%28java.lang.String%29) to get the parent.

Another solution via REST API:

```
Issue issue = getRestClient().getIssueClient().getIssue(task.getKey(), new NullProgressMonitor());
Field issueParent = issue.getField("parent");
if (issueParent  !=null){
    JSONObject jsonParent = (JSONObject)issueParent.getValue();
    BasicIssue partsedIssue = null;
    try {
        partsedIssue = new BasicIssueJsonParser().parse(jsonParent);
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("parent key: "+partsedIssue.getKey());
}
```